# How to "force" CRC files to appear when writing csv/parquet on HDFS in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, crc

I seem to have the opposite problem from the rest of the Internet - any search on the topic would throw thousands of questions on *how to **suppress** CRC files* when writing out using Spark.

When using Spark on a cluster and writing stuff out to the HDFS I can't see any of the `.crc` files I usually see on the local system. Any ideas how to "force" them to appear?

Comment: I think they don't appear (by default) on HDFS because the filesystem has that functionality built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach and see if .crc file is appearing on the hdfs folders.

```
val customConf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val fileSystemObject = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(customConf)
fileSystemObject.setVerifyChecksum(true)
```

Comment: no change unfortunately... could it be that I'm not seeing them when typing ```hdfs dfs -ls <path>``` and should include an option to ```-ls```?

Comment: fs.setWriteChecksum(true)
fs.setVerifyChecksum(true) can you try to set both configuration to true and see ?

Comment: Also, try with hdfs dfs -ls -la ?

Comment: no luck still...
```-la``` is not a valid ```hdfs dfs -ls``` option

Answer (score 0):

If you write to text file on HDFS - you need to call setWriteChecksum with "false". And you will have only one your file:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val conf = new Configuration()
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", uri)
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf)

// this is it!
hdfs.setWriteChecksum(false)

val outputStream = hdfs.create(new Path("full/file/path"))
outputStream.write("string to be written".getBytes)
outputStream.close()
hdfs.close()
```